# Интерактивная "консоль" на сайте

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, php

Как можно сделать нечто вроде консоли из http://codecademy.com на JS/PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет, совсем не претендую на элегантное решение, но попробовал сделать так:

```
HTML:
<section><input /></section>

JS:
$('input:last').focus();

$('section').on('keyup', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('input:last').attr('disabled','disabled');
     $('section').append('<div class="msg">Hello! Please gimme a work, masta!</div>').append('<input />');
     $('input:last').focus();
  }
});
```

Может кому понравится идея.

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/3C4j8/

P.S> почему то на динамически добавленных Input не работало событие $('input').on('keyup', callback); пришлось "костылять" со всей секции, может кто подскажет из за чего?

Comment: Из-за того, что в тот момент, когда навешивается событие, инпута не существует и по этому на него событие не вешается.

Раньше для этого юзал .live(), теперь использую делегирование:
http://jsfiddle.net/3C4j8/1/

Comment: Большое спасибо, попробую поковыряться с этим :)
Сохранил всё это в один html (css и js указал в head), открываю в браузере -- и консоль уже не интерактивна, ввести что-то нельзя. Почему?

Comment: JS Оберните в функцию `$(document).ready(function (){  /* код */ });`

Comment: Не помогло. http://troloload.ru/f/12729_1.html Подскажете, что не так?

Comment: @goudwine, вы саму библиотеку не подключили. Выше вашего JS-кода, добавьте:

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Deonis, спасибо! (правда, забыли http: в src)

Comment: Он не забыл, это вроде как универсальный способ подключения http/https в зависимости от того какой протокол использует ваш сайт.